# When Hermione removed her parents' memories, what happened to everyone else's memories of her?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

So I understand she modified her parents' memories, but what happened to her other family? Did they remember her, or did she remove everyone's? It would be suspicious if parents suddenly refused to acknowledge their daughter.

Or did her parents just disappear and emigrate to Australia then come back randomly and act like nothing happened?

Comment: The latter part of this question is answered here. They just came back home a few months later, presumably with lots of stories about their impromptu trip to Australia; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/did-hermione-ever-fix-her-parents-memories?rq=1

Comment: Everyone else would keep their memories. for example, in the second book, Gilderoy Lockhart loses his memory of who he is, but Harry and Ron still know who he is, and so does most of the wizarding world as he is famous

Comment: Is there any indication that Hermione **had** "other family"? Only her parents are ever mentioned. I think JKR has said that she deliberately kept Hermione's family small, as a balance to Ron's very large family (who are, to be honest, all much more interesting/useful characters, being witches and wizards), so it's possible that like Harry she has no living grandparents, and her parents also had no siblings (so no aunts or uncles, no cousins, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

## Others would remember her if she didn’t modify *their* memories.

Memory charms only work on the specific person or people they’re used on - as long as Hermione hadn’t modified the memories of everyone who knew her, they’d all still remember her.

## They wouldn’t find her parents, who had new names and moved.

While their memories were modified, Hermione’s parents wouldn’t be talking to anyone else who knew her because those people wouldn’t be able to find them - they’d moved and changed names. That was so the Dark Lord wouldn’t be able to track them, but it’d also then mean that their friends, neighbors, relatives, and other people who know them wouldn’t be able to find them either. Since Hermione’s parents wouldn’t remember them, and can’t be found, they wouldn’t be in contact with anyone they knew as Mr. and Mrs. Granger until Hermione unmodified their memories.

> “I’ve also modified my parents’ memories so that they’re convinced they’re really called Wendell and Monica Wilkins, and that their life’s ambition is to move to Australia, which they have now done. That’s to make it more difficult for Voldemort to track them down and interrogate them about me – or you, because unfortunately, I’ve told them quite a bit about you.” 
> <sub><sup>*-Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 6 (The Ghoul in Pyjamas)*</sup></sub>

For the time their memories were modified, Hermione’s other relatives as well as other people who knew her parents would probably wonder where they went, but they wouldn’t be able to find them to talk to  them, so they wouldn’t know they’ve forgotten their daughter. Once Hermione’s parents got back in contact with the people they knew as Mr. and Mrs. Granger, they’d already remember everything, and they and Hermione could make up a plausible excuse for their sudden absence.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of the question, according to an [interview](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/07/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript/) with Rowling, they came back

> Was Hermione able to find her parents and undo the memory damage?
>
> Rowling: Yes, she brought them home straight away.

They had to act like nothing extraordinary happened, because they couldn't talk about magic to their friends and acquaintances. Of course they would have to invent a really good explanation why they went away without telling anybody.