# Did Hermione use the Memory Charm Obliviate?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

When Hermione erases her parents' memories with the Memory Charm "Obliviate" she doesn't store them in a bottle for safe keeping.

To my knowledge Obliviate erases memories instead of hiding them or removing them for storage. So how could she have returned what was no longer there to return?

Edit:
Did she actually use Obliviate? In the movie she clearly says "Obliviate". Is it possible to cast a spell while uttering the words to a different spell? In the first movie she tells Ron that he is saying "Wingardium Leviosa" wrong implying that the wording is the reason the spell is not working. We have seen wizards cast spells without saying the words implying that there is a level of mastery involved. However Hermione states later that she has never performed the Obliviate spell so she would have no prior experience.

Comment: do we know that she did? (a bit snarky response there... ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell I don't think that's snarky; she was removing memories of things they weren't supposed to know.  Why would there be any reason to give them back?

Comment: I've seen a few quotes stating that in an interview JK Rowling has stated that after the war Hermione sought out her parents and returned their memories to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did Hermione ever fix her parents' memories?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/did-hermione-ever-fix-her-parents-memories), cf [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121542/98028) providing a JKR quote saying no memories were wiped, simply a mind trick-like spell, which she then lifted. Also see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4715/98028) to another version of the same question

Comment: She [didn't use a Memory Charm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4706/36526) in the first place.

Comment: Just noting that if this does get closed as a Duplicate, it's not that it's a bad question or that we expected you to search the entire site. It's just our way of grouping things together. You will still get points for the question being upvoted.

Comment: I had to update the question. @Kevin so can she cast a spell while uttering the words of a different spell. Or could it have been a derivative of Obliviate and thats why she said Obliviate?

Comment: Also I have not read the books so I don't know if she says something else when removing/altering her parents memories.

Comment: @rzaratx: Ah. In that case, the short answer is **the film lied to you.** In the books, it is not shown on-screen and is only mentioned in passing. She never calls it a Memory Charm, and later says she's never done a Memory Charm.